# NestJS: Microservices with Docker

Tags: docker, microservices, nestjs

I'm working with microservices and I have a problem. I have two NestJS applications with microservices. First one is `hybrid appliacation` and the second one is just a simple microservices with `app.listen()` function. Everything is set up in Docker-compose. I just want to send a simple `@EventPattern` and it fails. Second application don't receive any event. I was following this topic: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2532 but it didn't help at all. Here is some code I wrote:

`docker-compose-dev.yml`

```yaml
# First Server
  # --------------------------------------------------
  first-server:
    container_name: first-server
    image: project/firstserver
    build:
      context: ../first-server/
      args:
        UUID: ${UUID}
        UGID: ${GUID}
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-development}
    depends_on:
      - db-postgres
      - db-mongo
    user: "${UUID}:${GUID}"
    tty: true
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "3010"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3010:3010"
    volumes:
      - ../first-server:/app
    networks:
      - servers-network

  # Second Server
  # --------------------------------------------------
  second-server:
    container_name: second-server
    image: project/secondserver
    build:
      context: ../second-server/
      args:
        UUID: ${UUID}
        UGID: ${GUID}
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-development}
    depends_on:
      - db-postgres
      - db-mongo
    user: "${UUID}:${GUID}"
    tty: true
    expose:
      - "3100"
      - "3020"
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
      - "3020:3020"
    volumes:
      - ../second-server:/app
    networks:
      - servers-network

# Docker networks
# --------------------------------------------------
networks:
  servers-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: servers-network
```

**first-server:**

`main.ts`

```js
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
    const microservice = app.connectMicroservice({
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: 3010
        }
    });

    await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
    await app.listen(port);
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            useClass: TypeOrmPostgresConfigProvider,
            name: TypeOrmPostgresConfigProvider.connectionName,
            imports: [
                ConfigModule
            ]
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            useClass: TypeOrmMongoConfigProvider,
            name: TypeOrmMongoConfigProvider.connectionName,
            imports: [
                ConfigModule
            ]
        }),
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
            rootPath: join(__dirname, '../..', 'public/app')
        }),
        ClientsModule.register([
            {
                name: 'SERVICE_A',
                transport: Transport.TCP,
                options: {
                    host: '0.0.0.0',
                    port: 3010
                }
            }
        ])
    ],
    controllers: [
        AppController
    ],
    providers: []
})
```

`app.controller.ts`

```js
export class AppController {

    constructor(
        @Inject('SERVICE_A') private readonly client: ClientProxy
    ) {
    }

    async onApplicationBootstrap() {
        await this.client.connect()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('result');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    @Get('hello')
    getHello() {
        this.client.emit<any>('message_printed', new Message('Hi there!'));
        return 'Hello World printed';
    }

    @EventPattern('message_printed')
    async handleMessagePrinted(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
        console.log('first-server event!');
    }

}
```

**second-server:**

`main.ts`

```js
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
        AppModule,
        {
            transport: Transport.TCP,
            options: {
                host: '0.0.0.0',
                port: 3020
            }
        }
    );

    app.listen(() => console.log('Microservice is listening'));
}
```

`app.controller.ts`

```js
export class AppController {

    constructor() {

    }

    @EventPattern('message_printed')
    async handleMessagePrinted(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
        console.log('second-server event!');
    }

}
```

On both servers I have latest versions of NestJS. Docker version is 19.03.5.

Comment: Which code in this actually makes the connection?  It looks like you're trying to connect to 0.0.0.0 (IPv4 for "everywhere") but you actually need to pass in the server's Compose service name `first-server` as a host name.

Comment: First server is connecting with microservices. Where exactly should I pass `first-server` as a host name?

Comment: @JoeyMolley I've spent almost all the day researching this. And now I think I've finally figured it out: to work this, you should pass `first-server` in `ClientsModule.register` and also you have to pass the same value in `NestFactory.createMicroservice` as host value. This worked for me.

Comment: @RightNow I've tried this in two ways: `host: 'first-server'`, `host: 'first-server://0.0.0.0'`.
And I've got an error:
`{
  "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
  "code": "ENOTFOUND",
  "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
  "hostname": "first-server://0.0.0.0"
}`
I wrote this this both in `ClientModule.register` and `NestFacotry.createMicroservice`.

Comment: @RightNow I've made some progress but now I've got an error like this: `"code": "EADDRNOTAVAIL"`. Have you face it?

Comment: You don't have to pass `first-server://0.0.0.0`. Just `first-server`.

Comment: @RightNow Yep, I know. I wrote `first-server` but got this error with `EADDRNOTAVAIL`.

Comment: Too strange. :/ It worked for me